# Making a house in jogl java eclipse?

Tags: opengl, java, eclipse

here's what I'm trying to do:
One house, with 3 rooms, a window in two rooms, doors in the front and back of the house and into each room (the back door has to be through one of the rooms). I've added a picture as an example
I'm using JOGL 2.0, in eclipse.

Clarification: my question is how do I code it in java using jogl?

This is what I have so far:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    /* Floor */
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
    /* Ceiling */
    glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,1,1);
    glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
    /* Walls */
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(1,1,1);
    glVertex3f(-1,1,1);

    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);

    glVertex3f(1,1,1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(1,1,-1);

    glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
    glEnd();
```

[image]

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: That is the question, i.e. the task; and we're meant to code it.

Answer (score 2):

You should model the house in a 3D modeller like Blender and export it into .obj and read it into your application. Listing vertices for complex objects is cumbersome and listing them here as an answer doesn't add value.